# How long does it take for a badge to show up?

Tags: support, badges

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the badge description (if I am it's an odd badge) but I should have the Tenacious badge as I have 6 accepted answers and 50% of them (3) are 0 rated.

I've still not got the badge so I was wondering if it takes time for badges to process or something? I can't find somewhere saying it does.

Thanks

Comment: Approximately 24 hours. See [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/210346) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: It is not about accepted answers in total, it is about accepted answers that have a score of 0 being a substantial part of total answers given. At this time you have only two such questions. In other words, you get that badge if you keep on making an effort even while you are not obviously appreciated for it. Hence the title for the badge. You are currently mostly tenacious in building up your community standing, or so it appears.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your answers must be 10 days old before they qualify for the badge. E.g. It only counts answers that have had enough time to gather upvotes but haven't.

See [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)

*None* of your answers are nearly old enough yet, the oldest is barely 4 days old.